# How to annotate rails engine models with the annotate gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines, annotate

I  am trying to annotate my engines inside of a rails 6 project.

on the root app in the gem file I have

```
group :development do
  gem 'annotate'
end
```

and this works just as expected. When every I run migrations all my models annotate perfectly

now my engine Gemfile path is `components/engine_mame/Gemfile`

and I have

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

# Specify your gem's dependencies in engine_mame.gemspec.
gemspec

group :development do
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'pg'
end
```

but when I look at the models in my engine I do not have any annotations.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

method 1: set paths to models using generated rake task (`rails g annotate:install`), look for `model_dir` there and set paths using comma separator, e.g.

```
Annotate.set_defaults(
  'model_dir' => 'app/models, engine_mame/app/models',
)
```

method 2: set paths manually on each call (comma-seeparated, without space)

```
bundle exec annotate --model-dir app/models,engine_mame/app/models
```